# Issues with large directory and cp command

Tags: linux, bash, command-line, centos

I am trying to copy all jpgs from 1 directory to another but only new files and ones that have been updated.

I am using the following command:

```
\cp -uf /home/ftpuser1/public_html/ftparea/*.jpg /home/ftpuser2/public_html/ftparea/
```

And I am getting the error:

```
-bash: /bin/cp: Argument list too long
```

I am assuming that there are 2 many files in this directory for the cp command to work

I have also tried:

```
find  /home/ftpuser1/public_html/ftparea/ -name "*jpg" -exec cp -uf {} /home/ftpuser2/public_html/ftparea/
```

and got the following:

```
find: missing argument to `-exec'
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You forgot the `\;` argument in the end of the `find` command, that's why it isn't working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure to include the final “`\;`” to finish the command that `-exec` should execute.

Answer (score 0):

Using find you shouldn't have the brackets in quotes.  Try this

```
find  /home/ftpuser1/public_html/ftparea/ -name "*jpg" -exec cp -uf {} /home/ftpuser2/public_html/ftparea/ \;
```